# Social share integration with app and reporting to web service

Tags: ios, mgtwitterengine, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm developing an app for a client, which enables social sharing of client's product via twitter and facebook.

I successfully implemented sharing feature in twitter and facebook, and also I have to implemented report feature for these sharing in web service. To do this, I think these steps are sufficient:

1) Keep user's uniqueid for each platform in NSUserDefaults

2) Whenever user successfully shared content, Open NSUrlConnection to my web service and notified with user's unique id and shared content id.

3) Therefore, in web service, I can keep track of shared contents.

Is this really a good approach? Or, should I follow another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an analytics framework for something like this. I've used Flurry and Google Analytics for stuff like this. They both already have SDKs built that will connect to their web services. They are very easy to integrate.

[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com) is my personal favorite.

Comment: I already know "google analytic" and it looks bit messy to me, but I'm not aware of such reporting services like your suggestion flurry. I'm very impressed, it looks so easy. Thanks man.